# image does not show up in background of <tr>

Tags: jquery, css, image

I am facing a strange issue. I have a web application(developed in struts) and have 2 web pages, which are showing data in tabular format.

In the table, the header row has a background image so that the header would be distinguishable.

Now the issue is that the background image shows up in page A but does not show up in page B.

Some inputs :

1) The background is handled by CSS and same CSS class is used in both pages. Here is the class :

```
#reportArea table tr.tr-row-7 {
  background: url(../images/red-bg.png) repeat !important;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 36px;
  width: 100%;

}
```

2) I have checked with firebug Net monitor and found that red-bg.png is successfully loaded on both the page with HTTP code 200 OK

3) The data is loaded by an ajax function.

4) The class name tr-row-7 has given to row dynamically using jQuery. The function is something like this

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
  $("#reportArea table tr", this).each(function(i){$(this).addClass("tr-row-" + i);});
});
```

Both the pages using the same jQuery (`ajaxComplete()`) for row class assignment. Still page B is not able to show image in the background

Any ideas?

Comment: What does alert(i) says?

Comment: Please post the fiddle with table

Comment: Its working fine with your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NrKJe/2/

Comment: @SurendraVikramSingh : please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/NrKJe/6/, the classes were already in html, so it was working, here classes are assigned using jQuery, I guess we need to check jQuery as it is ajaxCompleted and fiddle does not have an ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this working. Actually, it was CSS/jQuery combined issue, from the long list of operations, jQuery was adding few parents to this table and that was causing the issue.

Due to this, the position of the image was disturbed and was displayed in out of page area.

Thank you all for your answers/comments, they got me working!

Answer (score 1):

You were using id `#reportArea` in CSS but the same was missing in HTML

```
<div id="reportArea">
  your table
</div>
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/NrKJe/5/

Comment: Hi, still no luck, I saw your fiddler part, in fiddler it is working fine, that means, there is something in ajaxComplete() part of it. Let me try in $(document).ready()

Comment: sorry, that was a fiddle creation mistake, have a look at this, I guess we need to fire some ajax function, then only will be able to see the ajaxCompleted() behavior. see this : http://jsfiddle.net/NrKJe/7/

Answer (score 0):

Make another css for table header row of page B, with same properties, and do the same....